# Riddles and ciphers / All good ways to flex the mind / Can you solve my task?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

**I have arrived new / Here with ciphers for your eyes. / Can you solve this task?**

```
>-\!} ;%[$%) , >-\!
>%=$!{} ;{%[[!) @{-)[ [- !)\
[$! ),{! %} )]**!}[

[$%} %} ^]}[ [$! }[,{[
*,[!{ ;%** <! }-(![$%)# {-[!
])[%* )!/[ ;! {!![
```

**Woe I dislike them, / Hints shall be revealed quite soon / Should it not be solved.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the text is:

> A basic substitution cipher, which we can pull apart using some mental frequency analysis and by looking for patterns. For example, if we guess `[$%} %}` => `THIS IS`, it starts to unravel pretty quickly to:
>
>  CODES WITHIN A CODE
>  CIPHERS WRITTEN FRONT TO END
>  THE NARE IS NULLEST
>
>  THIS IS JUST THE START
>  LATER WILL WE SOMETHING ROTE
>  UNTIL NEXT WE REET

However, I'm not sure if there's more to do, nor am I sure if

> the typos/nonsense words are deliberate or not...

Comment: You have solved it fast, / Typos not intentional. / There will be more soon.